# how to split numbers with python(such as 1. 2. 3.)

Tags: python

i would really like to know if there is any way to split a python string that listed with numbers like this string:

```
"1.this is should be 
the first item in the string
2.this is the second item"
```

to this list:

`['this is should be\nthe first item of the string','this is the second item']`

thanks a lot this would be really helpful.

Comment: I suggest using regular expressions (regexps), ie. module `re`.

Comment: Yes, here's a good one: ```" *\\d\\. *"```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this

```
import re

ls="1.this is should be the first item in the string2.this is the second item"

sp=re.split(r'\d+.',ls)

print(sp[1:])
```

#### Output Will Be :

> ['this is should be \nthe first item in the string\n', 'this is the
>   second item']

### but if you want it to be the same as your output you can use the following code

```
import re
ls="""1.this is should be 
the first item in the string
2.this is the second item"""

newlist=list()
sp=re.split(r'\d+.',ls)

for i in sp[1:]:
    if i.endswith('\n'):

        pos=i.rfind('\n')
        newlist.append(i[:pos])
else:
    newlist.append(i)    
print(newlist)
```

#### Output will be

> ['this is should be \nthe first item in the string', 'this is the second item']

Comment: This won't work if the string contains multilines which seems so in the question.

Comment: @MustafaAydın its working on multi-lines except its showing \n in the list

Comment: The desired output of OP doesn't have those though.

Comment: @MustafaAydın i just updated the code , tell me your review

Comment: If it `endswith` `"\n"`, its position is -1 right away; no need for `rfind`. Also, a `newlist.append(i.strip)` might replace all of that if block, which further means the `for` can be put in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better ways to do but, but here goes:

```
string = "1.this is should be the first item in the string 2.this is the second item"
lookingFor = 0
catch = false
array = []

for i in string:
   if lookingFor == str(i + 1):
      catch = true
   elif catch and i == ".":
      catch = false
      array.append("")
   else:
      array[lookingFor] += i

print(array)
```

Comment: Did you run this? Shouldn't `true`, `false` begin with capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

Replace these numbers by a sentinel value and then split on that value:

```
s = """1.this is should be
the first item in the string
2.this is the second item"""

sentinel = '!!!'

for i in range(5):  # adjust the range as needed 
    s = s.replace(f'{i}.', sentinel) 

s.split(sentinel)
```

Output is:

```
['',
 'this is should be\nthe first item in the string\n',
 'this is the second item']
```

You might want to get `s.split(sentinel)[1:]` to avoid the empty string, if `1.` is at the start of `s`.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output `['this is should be\nthe first item of the string','this is the second item']`. The items in the desired list doesn't end with newline character.

Comment: I interpreted that as OP forgetting to add a newline at the end of the word `'string'` in their desired output, since at no point any mention is made as to what should happen to newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = """1.this should be
the first item in the list
2.this is the second item
3.this is the third
one in the list"""

total_lines = len(val.splitlines())
the_list = [item[:(-1-len(str(line_no)) if line_no != total_lines-1 else None)]
                             for line_no, item in enumerate(val.split(".")[1:], start=2)]
# ['this should be\nthe first item in the list', 'this is the second item', 'this is the third\none in the list']
```

After splitting on `"."` (and ignoring the first element as it will be `1` alone), the strings will end as `"...\n3"`. So we should remove the `"\n"` and the numeric character. Since (I assume) it may go beyond 10, the string to ignore from the end should be of length `1+len(str(line_no))`; except for the last line, hence the if. We get the `line_no` thanks to `enumerate` by starting from 2 (as we ignored 1 already).

Answer (score -1):

separate with new line or comma

Comment: You can use the "\n" character. But I think they wanted it as an array.

Comment: You should expand on this answer. How would you separate by newline or comma? What's the output?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26061730)

Comment: @RamSharma: It may not be a _correct_ answer, but it appears to be _an_ answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney- I feel this answer required details to support his view

Comment: @RamSharma got it